# Hide only JW player bottom controls without initial loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jwplayer

I am using JW player. when player starts loading it shows 'Loading symbol' but if i set `controls: false` the loading icon also not appear while video start. is there any way to hide only bottom controls

[**Reference**](https://jsfiddle.net/bwcsdg1u/5/)

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player1");
playerInstance.setup({
    file:"",
    width: "100%",
    displaytitle: false,
    controls: false,
    primary: 'html5',
    mute:'false',
    autostart: true,
    advertising: {
          client: "vast",
          tag: ''
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using .jw-controlbar { display: none } in a style tag in your head tag? https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/css-skinning-reference.html#